# How to run a method and output while a user types in an input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have an online tool, I have built with rails that takes a user input and output the result on the same page upon clicking a button. Upon clicking the button a complex code runs on the input and shows the result.
How can I make the result appears while the user is typing the input, like real time capturing processing of the input.
I am using Rails 5.1.4 and Ruby 2.4.2p198

Comment: Run your code in a handler for an event like `keyup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `keyup` function and execute the handler function at real time when user types instead of when submit is clicked, I've created a simple fiddle, have a look

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/bLyovsj9/